# How to handle files selected by document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, file-upload, pug

I'm not sure where does the file go, when you do this. I've read a couple of tutorials but most of them just assume you only need to open the explorer window so you can upload your file. None of them concern themselves with what happens after this. My code opens a window on either windows or mac, but then... what? where does this file get stored, and how can I use it to upload to somewhere? Say I have this code in pug:

```
form.form-file(action='../public/javascripts/file_upload.js' method='POST' ondrop="../public/javascripts/drag_and_drop.dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);")
                            input#proof_address.input-file(type='file' multiple='')
                            .p-file.center
                                h5.mt-3 
                                p  Drag and drop your files, or use the "upload button"
                                button.btn.btn-red-wr.mb-4(type='button' id="button_upload" onclick="document.getElementById('input_upload').click();") Upload
                                input(id = "input_upload" name="files[]" type="file" style="display: none" )
```

how do I access the uploaded file in another javascript script so I can upload it to a database?

update: here's whats inside file-upload.js:

```
Parse.initialize(APP_ID,serverURL);
var Media = Parse.Object.extend("Media");

function saveFile(bufferBinary, name, mimetype, type, callback){
  var media = new Media();
  const data = Array.from(Buffer.from(bufferBinary, 'binary'));
  const file = new Parse.File(name, data, mimetype);
  file.save().then(function() {
    media.set('file', file);
    media.set('type', type);
    media.save().then((res) =>  {
      callback({res});
    }, (error) => {
      callback(error);
    });
  }, (error) => {
   callback(error);
  });

}

module.exports = {
    saveFile:saveFile,
};
```

Comment: Can you show what happens in "upload.php"? This will be the action which should happen after file upload.

Comment: @EKrol sorry for the late reply, I have updated the question to show what happens here. My fault, the legacy code contained that line and I never got to use it. For documentation purposes all my code is in javascript